# What type of pneumatic valves would represent the valves in the schematic?

Tags: pneumatic

What type of pneumatic solenoid valves would represent the valves in the schematic?

Specifically, the lower valves could be represented by a 5 port 4 way 2 position valve. This is because there is only one port with bidirectional flow for each side.

However, I'm not sure how to realize the upper valve system since there are 2 ports with bidirectional flow. Is there a way to realize this system with multi-port valves or does the upper system need to utilize direct acting (not pilot spool) valves?

[image: Pressure Swing Adsorption]

Comment: why are there two valves on the upper horizontal branch? A contious line implies flow /open valve, a dashed line closed valve? Is this a swing compression oxygen concentrator? then I don't understand the role of the upper horizontal branch.

Answer (score 0):

The valve symbols you show in your diagram are that of a simple gate valve, the symbol for the types of solenoid valves your wishing to represent are put together as such.....

[image]

These are just some examples....